# # Altair, unstake barchart + line with independent scale

Tags: python, visualization, altair, stacked-bar-chart

I have the following chart.
[image]
But I want this to not be stack on top of each other, but side by side like this example in seaborn:

`sns.barplot(data=df, x="island", y="body_mass_g", hue="sex")`

I tried a couple of different things but looks like it's not possible unless we use columns for the weeks in the x axis [article](https://anvil.works/blog/plotting-in-altair). But if I use different columns, then I can't have the line plot in an independent axis (error related with the facets) - Note that y axis for bar plot it's different for the y axis line plot.

This is my code below, do you think there is anyway to change it and make it work?

```
    # create line chart
    line = (
    alt.Chart(
        df_line,
        title= chart_title)
    .mark_line(interpolate="basis")
    .encode(
        x=alt.X("yearmonthdate(WEEK):T", title='Week'),
        y=alt.Y("PCT_LINE:Q", axis=alt.Axis(format='%'), title = 'Line'),
        tooltip=["yearmonthdate(WEEK):O", "value:Q"]
    )
    .properties(width=500, height=300)
    )

    # create bar chart
    bar = (
    alt.Chart(
        df_bars)
    .mark_bar(interpolate="basis")
    .encode(
        x=alt.X("yearmonthdate(week):T", title='Week'),
        y=alt.Y("value:Q", axis=alt.Axis(format='%'), title = y_axis_legend), #, stack=False
        color=alt.Color("variable:N", title= 'Legend'),
        tooltip=["yearmonthdate(WEEK):O", "variable:N", "value:Q"]
    )
    .properties(width=500,height=300)
    )
    bar

    plot = (line + bar).resolve_scale(y="independent")
    plot
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use the new xOffset channel as in [this example](https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/grouped_bar_chart2.html):

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd

source = pd.DataFrame({
    "Category":list("AAABBBCCC"),
    "Group":list("xyzxyzxyz"),
    "Value":[0.1, 0.6, 0.9, 0.7, 0.2, 1.1, 0.6, 0.1, 0.2]
})

alt.Chart(source).mark_bar().encode(
    x="Category:N",
    y="Value:Q",
    xOffset="Group:N",
    color="Group:N"
)
```